# Typescript error with jsonwebtoken decode

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#readme) to handle web tokens. Currently, I have a page that needs to decode the cookie to get the user_id. I create a function names getUserID and it works flawlessly but there is a typescript warning about the decoded value using jsonwebtoken.  Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

const TestPage = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState<number | null>(null)

  const getUserID = useCallback(() => {
    if (Cookies.get('user_token')) {
      const cookie = Cookies.get('user_token') || ''
      if (jwt.decode(cookie)) {
        const decoded: any = jwt.decode(cookie)
        const user_id =
          typeof decoded.user_id === 'number'
            ? decoded.user_id
            : parseInt(decoded.user_id)
        setUserId(user_id)
      }
    }
    return null
  }, [Cookies.get('user_token')])

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserID()
  }, [])

  return <div>User Id: {userId}</div>
}

export default TestPage
```

And this is the typescript error warning:

```
Type error: Argument of type 'string | (() => string)' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  15 |           typeof decoded.user_id === 'number'
  15 |              ? decoded.user_id
> 17 |             : parseInt(decoded.user_id)
     |                        ^
  18 | 
  19 |         setUserId(user_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fast and dirty

you can aferm it with this.

```
parseInt(decoded.user_id as string)
```

This tells TS that user_id will always be a string and never a function that returns a string. Only do this if you know this to be true.